# css sprite malfunction

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a bunch of images that I have consolidated into a single png. I am trying to use these images to make css sprite classes.

```
<style>
img.plusOne
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:url(acknowledgement.png) 0 0;
}
</style>

<body>
<img class="plusOne" src="acknowledgement.png" width="1" height="1" />
</body>
```

Instead of displaying the first icon in the png which is 50px by 50px, what is happening is that the whole png file is being squeezed into a 50 x 50 icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [need to fix retina sprite css issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371635/need-to-fix-retina-sprite-css-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `<img>` loads and displays the entire image.

Usually people use a `<div>` or `<span>` tag with `display:inline-block` for the sprite, instead of `<img>`

Comment: It seems to work fine here though: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_img

Comment: Yes, but notice the `src` of their images: The image itself is just a transparent box, not the spritesheet. W3Schools is an extremely unreliable source of learning and [should not be trusted](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: A List Apart has a great article on sprites: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 1):

Think of it exactly like this.

You have a window.  Person stands in front of window, now you can't see through the window.
What you need to do is set the person to be transparent so you can see through the window.

The image within the img class="plusOne" src="acknowledgement.png" width="1" height="1" /> needs to be a transparent GIF or PNG for this to worrect correctly.  You do NOT want it to be the same image you are using for a background image.

You can download a transparent GIF here:
http://www.unifiedwealthplanning.com/images/spacer.gif

Example in your code:

```
<img class="plusOne" src="http://www.unifiedwealthplanning.com/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to generate the CSS for your existing sprite - http://www.spritecss.com/